# electric windows broken

Tags: electrical, ford

Can anyone help just got home and have gone to do my electric windows up and non of them will go up I had an issue with the passenger side switch not doing the window up but would do it down but now non work at all and my windows are stuck down

Comment: Have you checked the fuses for the windows?

Comment: What type of Ford do you have (year/model)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electric Windows won't go up](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/electric-windows-wont-go-up)

Comment: @Chenmunka - The one you listed is the one which was closed *as a duplicate of **this question***. We should be nice and leave this one open.

Comment: If all of them suddenly stopped working then definitely check the fuse.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience this problem myself. After I bypass the switch by unplugging it and finding the hot up and hot down wires at the switch and make sure the windows do in fact go up and down, then I know it is the switch. Sometimes the contacts inside the switch get dirty and wont put the current through to the windows. I have removed the window switches and soaked them in purified water for an hour or so then blown them out with compressed air, spray some WD-40 in them and give that a try. If that doesnt work. Buy a new switch, or once you know it's the switch, buy a new switch and forget it